# Override browser "Find" feature

Tags: javascript, find, browser

I'm wondering whether it's possible to use JavaScript to intercept or prevent the user from using the browser's "Find" feature to find text on the page. (Trust me, I have a good reason!) I'm guessing the answer is "no," beyond the obvious intercepting Cmd/Ctrl+F.

A second-best solution would be to intercept the text highlighting that the browser performs during a Find. Is there any way to do this, in any browser?

Comment: Just curious, what is the reason?

Comment: It's for a web-based text editor. Ideally, I'd be able to intercept every Find and display my own Find & Replace dialogue. Having two different Finds is just confusing! There's more to it than that, but basically, the browser's Find would just be confusing in the context of this app.

I guess I'll just intercept Cmd/Ctrl+F and pray that the user is using the standard keyboard shortcut.

Comment: intercepting Ctrl+F is slightly dangerous as it may be mapped differently in other languages, but I think it's your best bet. Because even if you managed to detect a "Find", how would you find out what the original search string was, when the search was case insensitive? And whether the "Find next / Find previous" button was used? Sounds like mission impossible to me.

Comment: I have never seen any web application - including all kinds of editors - that does this. But I admit, that I haven't even tried it (because I simply don't expect the find operation on Ctrl-/Cmd-f for a web app). If it can be done, and if it is demanded by many users, then you will most likely find a solution by looking at what the "big ones" are doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not without the help of a browser-specific extension I think, if at all. This is a process that is entirely outside the JavaScript context.

Comment: You're sure there aren't any events fired when a browser Find highlights some text on the page? In any browser? Since you can copy the selected text to the clipboard, I would think there would be a change in the selected text property somewhere, which you could distinguish from a mouse or keyboard event that would normally select text.

Comment: @Trevor in Firefox, the "find" selection is different from the standard selection. It can not be copy+pasted, nor deleted. I'm 99% sure this is not a normal selection and the selected text property will not change. (I can't test it in depth right now but I'd be surprised if I turned out to be wrong.) In IE 8, though, it looks like the normal selection is manipulated. You may be successful there.

Comment: @Trevor Pretty definite for FF, I tested http://api.jquery.com/select/ the example doesn't work in IE either but that may be down to a text input specific behaviour.

Comment: I'm disappointed that this is the case, though I'd suspected as much. Think of something like Google Books as an example of what I'm trying to accomplish—the "Find" feature in your browser is guaranteed to provide a bad experience. You really want to use the page's own search feature. Google overrides the keyboard shortcuts for "Find," but it's still accessible via your browser's menu or non-standard keyboard shortcuts. A real pity.

Comment: BTW, that's all no longer true. PDF.js and many other apps rely on overriding native browser find functionality.

Comment: ...or not. They seem to just catch `Ctrl+F`/`Cmd+F`, if you choose `Find` from the menu it's still the native one.

Answer (score 2):

To disable the effect pf the find feature, you can use this [Jquery Plugin](https://github.com/seangransee/Disable-CTRL-F-jQuery-plugin).

It can also be done with plain JavaScript, as follows:

```
        function disableFind() {
            var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");
            var end = false;
            for(let idx in all){
                let currentElement = all[idx];
                let html = currentElement.innerHTML;
                if(!html) continue;
                let newHTML = "";
                for(var i = 0; i < html.length; i++) {
                    newHTML += html[i];
                    if (html[i] == '<') end = true;
                    if (html[i] == '>') end = false ;
                    if (end == false) {
                        newHTML += '<span style="position:absolute; left:-9999px;">.</span>';
                    }
                    if (html[i] == ' ') newHTML += ' ';   // insert a space if the current character is a space
                }
                currentElement.innerHTML = newHTML;
            }


        }
```

Additionally, you can prevent the default behavior of CTRL/CMD+F, with the following code:

```
 window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
     if(e.which == 70 && (e.ctrlKey || e.metaKey)) e.preventDefault(); 
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really, absolutely have to do that - then there's a (really bad) solution: Render the page as an image.

Comment: No, I need to preserve other behaviors; for instance, I want the user to be able to select text with the mouse, and enter text. I just want to avoid them selecting it with Find.