# How to hide Find Bar in browser? (cancel Ctrl+F by javascript after it was already invoked)

Tags: javascript, browser, find

When user presses Ctrl+F on keyboard, browser shows a `find box` where user can type some text and browser finds occurrences of that text on the current webpage. I would like to keep this feature, but once my users clicks somewhere on the webpage, for example on a certain input element, I want chrome to cancel the finding - to stop - to hide the find box.

How to do that in JavaScript?
At least in chrome...

I know there is a possibility to intercept all keyboard events and cancel the Ctrl+F keystroke in general so the find bar never appears, but this is not my goal, as I wrote I want this to be preserved, but auto-hide programatically.

I noticed that the find box disappears if navigating away from the webpage, I tried to 'navigate away' by adding a #hash to the location.href but this didn't seem to work. I actually cannot navigate away, but maybe some similar hack could help?

Comment: I don't think this is possible using Javascript. I believe you can only achieve this by implementing your own `Find Box`

Comment: This seems like the sort of browser feature they wouldn't allow you to access via JS. The only thing that springs to mind would be to trigger an escape key event, although I expect this would also be ignored.

Comment: The following post indeed confirms you can't override the browser "Find" feature: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2760780/override-browser-find-feature?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(window).keypress(function (e) {
  return !(e.which == 102 && e.ctrlKey)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Using jQuery this code is correctly working in Firefox. But Chrome didn't generate event if you are using Ctrl+F shortcut. And you can't rewrite browser`s behaviors using JS. You can rewrite it if you will write the plugin for browser